# Why aren't there any unicorns?

Tags: feature-request

The Big Three<sup>TM</sup> sites get sparkly unicorns today. Where are *our* sparkly unicorns? I feel unloved.

Hmph.

Comment: In all seriousness, the trilogy is toned down this year from previous years, and you know that :p ~ But imagine when this is no longer the playground of just geeks and is the playground of the world ... they may not understand such jokes.

Comment: @dra +1 yep! Precisely! My sister thought I was slightly mental when I showed her the unicorns on SO! =S

Comment: Shouldn't this question be titled "Eeeek! Where are my unicorns?"

Comment: @Robusto: one does not say "eeek" around unicorns. It's just Not Done™.

Comment: Unicorns are not real.

Comment: @Robusto The correct form would be, "Egad!  Where are my Unicorns?"

Answer (score 6):

haha I didn't realize this! =P I just came here from SO & meta to see what the unicorns looked like here and there aren't any! =( How sad!

Possibly Jeff & Team thought it would (in some way) scare/confuse people new to the site and/or the whole stackexchange concept.

Only the people who've hung around meta a little know about the sick desires SO folk have for unicorns, waffles, ponies , freehand circles, jquery etc.

Answer (score 5):

The unicorns are in the garden. Eating roses and lillies. That's how they roll.

I can see at least two of them right now, just by looking out of my browser window:

[image]

Generally speaking, if you can't see something, that means that you must have a bug installed in your PC. Simply remove it, and everything will work again. Hope that helps.

Comment: Aaaaaah! Make it go away!!! (The second unicorn, that is.)

Comment: Zombie unicorns I can believe, but Gary Busey is just a myth.

Comment: This might be the scariest thing I have seen all month.